# Frequency of Oscillations about Circular Orbit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, spring, centrifugal-force

I'm trying to figure out the frequency of small oscillations about the basic circular path of a mass at the end of a spring, being spun around a table. I understand that the spring will stretch out a bit, and then it will have a stable circular orbit. Moreover, introducing a little bit of extra stretching will cause it to oscillate about this orbit, but I have no idea what approach to take. I've seen things like binomial expansions and the like to calculate small changes to orbits, but I can't even seems to get a good, functional equation to describe the set up. Can someone give me a little guidance?

Comment: Start without the oscillations. While spinning, the mass is accelerating with $a = v^2/r$ as for circular motion. Drawing a free body diagram, we see that there is exactly one force on the mass: the pull of the spring. This tells you the force on the spring in the steady state where there's no oscillation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The potential energy is $U\left(r\right) = k \left(r - r_0\right)^2 / 2$, where $r_0$ is  the equilibrium position of the spring. Since this is a central potential (depends only on $r$), angular momentum $L$ is conserved, and we can use the concept of an effective potential energy (see equation 335 [here](http://www2.ph.ed.ac.uk/~egardi/MfP3-Dynamics/Dynamics_lecture_20.pdf))
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
U_{eff}\left(r\right) &=& \frac{L^2}{2 m r^2} + U\left(r\right) \\
&=& \frac{L^2}{2 m r^2} + \frac{1}{2} k \left(r - r_0\right)^2
\end{eqnarray}
$$

The equilibrium position $r_*$ is then given by
$$
0 = \frac{d U_{eff}}{dr} \Bigg|_{r=r_*} = -\frac{L^2}{mr_*^3} + k\left(r_* - r_0\right) \ \ \  \Rightarrow \ \ \ u^4 - u^3 = C,
$$
where $u = r_*/r_0$ and $C = L^2 / \left(m k r_0^4\right)$.

The angular frequency of small oscillations about $r=r_*$ is then
$$
\omega = \left(\frac{1}{m} \frac{d^2 U_{eff}}{dr^2} \Bigg|_{r=r_*} \right)^{1/2} = \left(\frac{k}{m} + \frac{3 L^2}{m^2 r_*^4}\right)^{1/2}
$$

Now it remains to solve for $u$ in $u^4 - u^3 = C$.

Comment: Why do we take the second derivative of the potential?

Comment: The Taylor expansion of $U_{eff}\left(r\right)$ is $U_{eff}\left(r_*\right) + k_{eff} \left(r - r_*\right)^2 / 2 + O\left(r^3\right)$ (since $dU_{eff}/dr$ at $r_*$ is $0$), where $k_{eff} = d^2U_{eff}/dr^2$ evaluated at $r=r_*$ is an effective spring constant. If that's not clear, note that $F_{eff}\left(r\right) = -dU_{eff}/dr = - k_{eff} \left(r-r_*\right) + O\left(r^2\right)$. The angular frequency of small oscillations is then $\left(k_{eff}/m\right)^{1/2}$.